# Full width (vw viewport) image inside fixed parent container

Tags: css

Im trying to accomplish this:

http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/oKBIu?editors=110

```
.child-div {
width: 100vw;  
position: relative;  
left: calc(-50vw + 50%);}
```

but instead of a "child-div" i want to target an img-class, like this:

http://codepen.io/dantveita/pen/ZGdKmd

```
.parent-div img {
width: 100vw;
position: relative;
left: calc(-50vw + 50%);}
```

When i do this, im getting a horizontal scrollbar, and im not sure why. Could anyone explain this to me. And if possible, provide a solution?

Thanks

Comment: The most obvious solution is just to close the container...have your full width div then open a new container. The title 'container' is just a class...not an absolute requirement that it hold **everything all at the same time**.

Comment: That is the obvious choice yes. But im doing this to post-images in a wordpress-blog template, where im not really sure how I would go about closing paragraphs when media (with the specified img-class) is inserted into the text.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `position: relative`, moving the image to the left doesn't actually take it outside of the document flow, so, according to the browser, it still thinks the image is sticking out.

Because there are no containing elements, there's also no need to use viewport-width over a percentage. For some reason, using viewport-width instead of a percentage adds a little extra space on the right, underneath the scrollbar, even when the image is absolutely positioned.

However, this works:

```
.parent-div img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You may also want to remove the `width="1400px"` from your image tag, as it isn't necessary and may cause inheritance issues later on.

Comment: Note: 100% is better than 100vw for this purpose because vw includes the width of the scroll bar, if one is present. On your [working example](http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/oKBIu?editors=110), if you increase the height of the `parent-div`, the full-width div will also stick out slightly.

Comment: This is good, thank you. But i dont want to take my images out of content flow. The whole idea is to have images stay in content, but stretch full width even though the rest of the content is constrained to the fixed with. (hence the loremipsum paragraphs above and below)

Giving the imageclass a `display:block` actually fixed the scrollbar issue. But obviously a "new" issue appear, just like youre saying (my osx was set to hide scrollbars so wasnt aware of this).

Comment: Is there a way to compensate for the scrollbar-thingy while still using the "vw-trick", or a way to get the same effect; full-width image-class, following content, inide fixed parentcontainer?

Comment: Well, you could use `'overflow-x: hidden'` on the `body`, assuming there's no other content on the site that would need a horizontal scroll.

Comment: You could also add a very large margin to any paragraph that follows your image, as long as you know the image's height. 
`.parent-div img + p {
  margin-top: 250px;
}`

Comment: Thanks alot. I guess I have enough to go on from here, but one last question. Are there any obvious reasons one should not hide body overflow-x on a responsive site?

Comment: You just need to be careful that you aren't setting large, static widths on anything, especially at small sizes and in fluid layouts. By default, those would cause a horizontal scrollbar if they extend past the edge of the page. While that isn't ideal, with `overflow: hidden`, you make it impossible for anyone to view that content at all, which is worse.  Especially make sure that images have variable widths. Also, Paulie's comment on your original question makes sense. If you are able to change the html to remove the image from the `.container` class altogether, this would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to go with

```
.parent-div img {
display:block;
width: 100vw;
position: relative;
left: calc(-50vw + 50%);}
```

on the img-class for now, while hiding overflow-x, until something comes up that makes hiding the scrollbar prevent users from viewing content.

The reason for using this method, and not closing the "previous" container (which would be the obvious choice) is that i want a quick solution for a wordpress blogtemplate, where all images given a specific img-class will stretch full width, when media is inserted from post-editor.

Heres an example of the effect im looking for (theverge.com is obviously closing containers):
http://www.theverge.com/2015/8/4/9090897/mlb-bam-live-streaming-internet-tv-nhl-hbo-now-espn